# Terminology for (new-old) / new

Tags: terminology

The term percent change is commonly used to describe $\frac{new - old}{old}\times 100$ which is the fraction of the old value by which it has grown.  There is a related concept which is $\frac{new - old}{new}\times 100$ which is the fraction of the new value which is attributed to the change.  Is there a common term for this?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, but I haven't ever seen a term for it

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Percentage change = $\frac{new - old}{old}\times 100$

From my experience and research, there is not a common term for:
$\frac{new - old}{new}\times 100$.

### Claim

That being said, I'd like to stake my claim and coin the corresponding term. It is to be known thus, as **percentage change with respect to the new value**.

Comment: Ya, it is super common concept, and I feel like there really should be an existing term.  When discussing growth like this, one would usually say that "X grew 100% from 25 to 50", but there should be a concept of "50% of the current value of X was due to change".

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly called the *relative change*, which may (but need not) be expressed as a percentage. The difference `new - old` is the *absolute change*.